# Is applicationDidBecomeActive: invoked on older (non multitasking) devices (YES/NO)?

Tags: iphone, multitasking

Just as the title goes. Or will it invoked on the first run of the application? May I count on it, and treat it as kind of a part of applicationDidFinishLaunching:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES. The docs indicate it is iOS2.0 and later which predates multi-tasking iOS.

> This method is called to let your application know that it moved from the inactive to active state. This can occur because your application was launched by the user or the system.

[ios developer center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. It exists in the older SDK, but it's used to indicate when your app is closed when, say, a phone call comes in. It isn't run on first launch, so you shouldn't treat it like `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. `didBecomeActive` is distinct from `willEnterForeground` - it serves a different purpose.

Comment: Seems it is invoked on an iPhone 3G with iOS 4+. I'm just testing it.

Comment: I need to check a settings bundle variable on every app launch wheter it is just a simple entering foreground or it is an actual launch on older devices. What to do then?